# Shortcut to select all SQL text in Access

Tags: ms-access, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

When working in the SQL view in MS Access, is there a shortcut to select all the text in a SQL query.

For example, most text editors in Windows follow the {Ctrl+ a} combination, but this doesn't seem to have any affect within Access. Is there some other combination?

It is useful when copying text from an outside editor into the Access SQL query creator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS-Access 2016

Create a new SQL view, write some text and then press F2.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Many thanks @McNets

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.